# Empty rows depending on another column

Tags: mysql

Right now I'm having this issues with my table

`Name       Practice
 Ben        Private
            Private`

I want to get rid of the second private value.

I've tried 
`Update tablename
SET Practice = CASE
WHEN Name LIKE NULL THEN NULL
END`

But it comes back by treating all my name values as null.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE

Ok I might have oversimplified my issue

```
Name Establishment Practice
Ben  Hospital 1    Private
     Hospital 2    Private
```

Also I have more than i'd say 500 entries like this in my table of 7000 entries.

I want to get rid of the 2nd private in this case because both private values correspond to one physician.

Some physicians have more than 2 hospitals to their name therefore more than 2 privates.

Sorry for the mis-communication.

Comment: hi guys updated my question but thanks for the answers so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html)

```
delete from table_name where name is null and practice='private';
```

Answer (score 0):

If by *get rid of the second private value* you mean you want to delete the second row then

```
DELETE FROM tablename
 WHERE Name is NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/516d1/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You need Delete and not Update

```
Delete from tableName where Name is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
UPDATE abc SET practice ='CASE' WHERE name LIKE ''
```

This is not agood practice for keeping name field blank

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE NULL` will not result true but a `NULL` on anything. You have to use `IS NULL`.

***Example***:

```
mysql> select null like null, null is null;
+----------------+--------------+
| null like null | null is null |
+----------------+--------------+
|           NULL |            1 |
+----------------+--------------+
```

This is wrong:

```
Update tablename 
  SET Practice = CASE WHEN Name LIKE NULL THEN NULL END
```

Change it as:

```
Update tablename 
  SET Practice = CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Practice END
```

Comment: hi i'm still getting back 0 rows affected